# Qual a diferença entre Sujeito oculto e Sujeito indeterminado?

Tags: gramática, sujeito-indeterminado

Tenho uma dúvida ao comparar o sujeito oculto que se dá pela desinência verbal com o sujeito indeterminado quando o verbo está na 3a. pessoa do plural. Qual o critério que separa esses 2 casos? Algumas fontes que encontro sugerem que sempre que o verbo se encontra na 3a. pessoa do plural (sem o sujeito explícito), o sujeito é categorizado como indeterminado, sem maiores explicações, como se essa condição fosse parte da definição. Outras separam o sujeito oculto do indeterminado com a ideia de que apesar de não estar explícito, ele pode ser identificado em um caso e não no outro. Se esse é o caso, então haveria situações em que "Deviam estar aqui há muito tempo!" possui um sujeito que deve ser categorizado como oculto ao invés de indeterminado, quando se sabe exatamente a quem o interlocutor se refere pelo contexto? E analogamente, haveria situações em que "Compramos o jantar hoje." seria indeterminado, devido a uma ambiguidade gerada pela existência de várias pessoas no recinto onde o falante disse a oração, com várias combinações fazendo sentido?

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro é interessante ver-lhes as definições:

> Sujeito Oculto
>
> Aquele que não está representado por meio de palavras na oração, **mas pode ser identificado pela desinência verbal ou contexto**

> Sujeito Indeterminado
>
> Aquele que não se refere a uma pessoa determinada ou não se pode identificar, e se expressa na terceira pessoa do plural, pelo pronome indeterminado “se” ou infinitivo impessoal.

Importante clarificar que não, o verbo estar na terceira pessoal não faz parte da definição de sujeito indeterminado, mas é um dos poucos modos conhecidos para escrever uma oração com sujeito indeterminado, tornando útil mencioná-lo na definição.

Vejamos este exemplo:

“Maria e João chegaram no Bar. Anunciaram a morte do rei”

pode ter sujeito oculto ou indeterminado. Se "anunciaram" estiver sendo usado como "a morte do rei foi anunciada" ou se o agente for outro, mas não se sabe, então, é sujeito indeterminado. Se Maria e João houverem anunciado a morte do rei, a oração tem sujeito oculto, pois o sabemos por contexto. A frase é bem ambígua.

Então, sim. Contexto é importante. Da segunda pergunta, vê-se a resposta na própria definição: *pode ser identificado pela desinência verbal*. Tanto que sujeito oculto também é chamado de sujeito desinencial.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Então é possível a existência do sujeito oculto na 3a. pessoa do plural sem que haja essa repetição do exemplo, sendo o contexto dado pelo conteúdo da oração? E igualmente, é possível indeterminar qualquer outra terminação verbal sem ser a 3a. pessoa do plural? Me parece que o cerne da questão se dá em definir o que significa "identificar". Acabei entendendo que o sujeito é indeterminado quando existe a ideia de pronomes indefinidos, como "alguém", e oculto nos outros casos.

Comment: @AllanFelipe, chegas a ser filosófico, no bom sentido. Se bem entendi: quando o sujeito da oração é indeterminado, é impossível determiná-lo, i.e., é impossível responder a pergunta "quem fez isso?". Sim, podes dizer que é impossível respondê-la para "alguém matou o gato", mas podes escrever "alguém"; para "cantaram ao serem libertados", não podes escrever nada, pode ter sido um alienígena ou um ser quadridimensional cujas nossas palavras são incapazes de descrevê-lo ou uma pedra. Ou seja, quando a pergunta é irrespondível.

Comment: Ok, concordamos que em "alguém matou o gato", o sujeito é determinado simples pois o que importa é a existência da palavra "alguém". Mas e se no decorrer de uma história (não necessariamente uma oração antes, como nos exemplos mais comuns) fosse possível detectar sem nenhuma ambiguidade quem cantou, em "cantaram ao serem libertados", esse sujeito seria classificado como oculto ou ainda como indeterminado? E também, há orações em que há um "nós" ou "vocês" oculto (ao invés de "eles"), por exemplo, e o sujeito é classificado como indeterminado? São as duas situações que estão me causando dúvida.

Comment: @AllanFelipe, nesse teu exemplo, o sujeito de "cantaram" não é indeterminado — determinaste-o na própria pergunta —, mas o sujeito não está explicito na oração, portanto, é sujeito oculto. Em uma frase com “nós” ou “vós” ou “vocês” etc., o sujeito é “eu e outra coisa (al)”, “tu e al”, “você e al” etc., portanto, é respondível. Se entendi tudo corretamente.

Comment: Obrigado, a primeira está respondida, sendo que é o contexto geral que indetermina o sujeito. Quanto a segunda me refiro a casos com sujeito oculto como "Vamos à praia". Caso haja ambiguidade, por algum motivo de contexto, em relação às pessoas as quais esse "nós" oculto se refere (e igualmente com um "eu", "vocês", etc... ocultos), a classificação seria indeterminado?

Comment: @AllanFelipe, vou usar "[al](https://dicionario.priberam.org/al)" para facilitar a minha vida. "Vamos à praia", quem foram à praia? O tal eu e al; é respondível então, ou seja, não é indeterminado. "Nós" se refere a eu e, pele menos, mais al; "vós" se refere a você e, pelo menos, mais al; "vocês" se refere a "você" e mais al. Interessante que quando "eles mataram a vizinha" tem sujeito determinado, "eles" se refere a "ele" e, pelo menos, al mais.

Comment: Ok, seria a existência dessa parte determinada que faz você chamar sempre de oculto então? Como é "eu + al", a existência do "eu" já determina uma parte do sujeito; como é "você + al", a existência do "você" já determina uma parte do sujeito. No caso em que não se pode determinar o "eles", a parte oculta é "al + al".