# Sujeito oculto e indeterminado - 3º pessoa do plural desinência causa ambiguidade em saber quem é quem. Sexualidade

Tags: sujeito

Houve questionamento sobre na plataforma 9 meses, contudo usuário de nome Schiive deixou-a insolucionada. Citou este exemplo transcrito link sua resposta:

[...]“Maria e João chegaram no Bar. Anunciaram a morte do rei”

pode ter sujeito oculto ou indeterminado. Se "anunciaram" estiver sendo usado como "a morte do rei foi anunciada" ou se o agente for outro, mas não se sabe, então, é sujeito indeterminado. Se Maria e João houverem anunciado a morte do rei, a oração tem sujeito oculto, pois o sabemos por contexto. A frase é bem ambígua.

Então, sim. Contexto é importante. Da segunda pergunta, vê-se a resposta na própria definição: pode ser identificado pela desinência verbal. Tanto que sujeito oculto também é chamado de sujeito desinencial.

[...]

Usuário de nome Allan Felipe explica apesar dos dados passados não compreender o fato pois o Schiive afirma ser o termo "alguém mais pronome" na desinências situações do verbo no plural identificar se ele é frase tem sujeito indeterminado ou não. Se for alguém + alguém é indeterminado por outro lado eu + ele determinado porque sabe-se todos os praticantes. Vejo porém ter pouca ajuda pois eles pode se referir tanto a nós de forma indireta quanto a eles de forma direta. Exemplo: um transauente que vê duas meninas comendo um bolo poderia falar: "As modelos comeram o bolo". Indeterminando-o ver-se-ia : comeram o bolo. Concluindo: quem comeu o bolo? elas ou eles a desinência não funciona para a 3º pessoa do singular. Devido a questão sexualidade indefinida. Fico grato!

Comment: Francamente, não entendo como essa frase: "Maria e João chegaram no Bar. Anunciaram a morte do rei” pode ser usada como "a morte do rei foi anunciada".  O sujeito (Maria e Jõao) está oculto mas a frase não quer dizer: "a morte do rei foi anunciada [por eles". Isso é uma frase passiva; Anunciaram a morte do rei, não, é ativa.

Comment: Você precisa indicar o **link** da pregunta a qual você se refere.

Comment: Segue o link apoio: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8675/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-sujeito-oculto-e-sujeito-indeterminado

Comment: O verbo anunciaram tem qual sujeito? fico grato resposta

Comment: O verbo não anuncia o sujeito: o sujeito da frase é oculto. [Eles] anunciaram a morte do rei. Será que foi preciso repetir a mesma coisa?

Comment: Passei um tempo escrevendo essa resposta. Será que você não vai responder?

Comment: Ok. obrigado compreendi.

Comment: Você não vai aceitar a minha resposta?

Comment: Não entendi qual é a pergunta. Qual foi, @Lambie?

Answer (score 0):

"Maria e João chegaram no Bar. Anunciaram a morte do rei”

Sujeito oculto de "anunciaram": **Maria e João** ou **eles**.

Definição de sujeito oculto ou indeterminado:

> Sujeito oculto ou sujeito elíptico: é aquele que não está explícito na
> oração, mas pode ser determinado pela flexão número-pessoa do verbo,
> ou por sua presença em alguma oração antecedente.
>
> Exemplo:
>
> Gosto de viajar todos os anos. (sujeito oculto “eu”, determinado pela
> desinência verbal)

[sujeito oculto](https://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/tipos-sujeito.html)

É preciso não confundir uma forma passiva: **A morte do rei foi anunciada [por eles]**.
Com: **Anunciaram a morte do rei**. que é uma forma ativa do verbo.

Outro exemplo:
Ele e a minha amiga sairam de casa cedo. Mas chegaram tarde no jantar.

- sujeito oculta na frase acima: [Eles] chegaram tarde no jantar. ou [Ele e a minha amiga] chegaram tarde no juntar.