# Questão de análise sintática: Sujeito oculto

Tags: sintaxe, conjunções, orações-subordinadas, sujeito

Tenho estudado gramática dissecando grupos oracionais até obter uma análise sintática completa de cada oração presente neles, gostaria que alguém pudesse me elucidar em um ponto específico acerca desse grupo complexo a seguir:

[image]

Sendo as palavras em preto conjunções ou locuções conjuntivas (como no caso principal); as em verde sendo predicativos; marrom, advérbio; azul, verbo ou locução verbal (oração subordinada 2); roxo, complemento verbal de algum tipo; vermelho, sujeito.

Nesse caso está certa minha análise das três orações? E caso esteja posso afirmar que o sujeitos das orações subordinadas são ocultos? Pois sabemos que são “ela”, mas não estão dentro da oração, ou seja, são ocultos, certo?

Fico grata se puderem me ajudar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sujeito oculto e indeterminado - 3º pessoa do plural desinência causa ambiguidade em saber quem é quem. Sexualidade](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/9205/sujeito-oculto-e-indeterminado-3%c2%ba-pessoa-do-plural-desin%c3%aancia-causa-ambiguidad)

Comment: Não chega a ser oculto. Se subentende: é porque **ela** não quer saber da principal. O 2 não funciona.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qual a diferença entre Sujeito oculto e Sujeito indeterminado?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8675/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-sujeito-oculto-e-sujeito-indeterminado)

Answer (score 1):

Não consegui entender o modo como você dividiu e analisou esse período. O que você chamou de "oração principal", na verdade é o período inteiro. E o que você chamou de "oração subordinada 1" se sobrepõe ao que chamou de "oração subordinada 2".

Parece-me que a análise desse período ficaria mais clara se entendermos que o "é" está aí como um verbo vicário, isto é, substituindo o verbo anterior, a saber, "não atendeu". Trata-se, na verdade, da oração principal.

Deste modo, a frase "Se ela não atendeu o telefone, **é** porque não quer saber da gente" equivale a: "Se ela não atendeu o telefone, **não atendeu** porque não quer saber da gente."

Assim, a oração principal é, na verdade, apenas o "é", que faz as vezes de "não atendeu".

A análise seria esta:

Oração subordinada 1 (condicional): "Se ela não atendeu o telefone,"

Oração principal: "é" = "[ela] não atendeu [o telefone]"

Oração subordinada 2 (causal): "porque não quer saber da gente".

Desse modo, há um sujeito determinado simples na oração subordinada 1. Na oração subordinada 2, o sujeito é oculto, elíptico ou desinencial, estando bastante claro que é "ela" quem não quer saber da gente.

Note-se que esse uso vicário do verbo "ser" mantém sempre o verbo na terceira pessoa do singular, independente do sujeito que ele esteja substituindo.

Comment: entendi sua resposta, mas vc esta totalmente seguro que é isso? Pergunto por conta da certa relatividade das regras gramaticais e devido ao fato de estar estudando para vestibular

Comment: Sim, estou seguro. Pesquise por "verbos vicários" e a explicação ficará mais clara.

Comment: muito obg pela ajuda!

Comment: de nada! não se esqueça de marcar a questão como resolvida! :-)